# publish jar dependencies with 'maven-publish' plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, maven-publish, fatjar

I have a gradle project in IntelliJ IDE in java.
my dependencies is like this:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.2'
compile group: 'com.intellij', name: 'annotations', version: '12.0'
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.1'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
compile files('libs/someJar.jar')
}       


 publishing {
publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        groupId group
        artifactId 'mylibrary'
        version version
        from components.java
        artifact sourceJar
    }

}
}
```

the problem is when I publish my project in the published jar I didn't find somejar.jar so how can I publish it too.
I want all classes in someJar.jar be next to my main package.

Comment: A deleted answer says you can look at `'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'` and see if it helps